# Trying to set and get attribute from one class to another via a 3rd class in JAVA

Tags: java, jsf, httpsession, facescontext

I have a bean class which looks like this

```
@ManagedBean(name = "usingBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2668727340500045081L;

    String loginId;

}
```

I set this bean attributes in a filter class.

I am trying to get this attribute in another bean class

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{usingBean}")
private UserInfo user;

public UserInfo getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(UserInfo user) {
    this.user = user;
}
UserInfo neededBean = (UserInfo) context.getApplication()
                .createValueBinding("#{usingBean}").getValue(context);
                return neededBean.getLoginId();
```

It says null when I try to print it, but it does get inserted into the DB.  It does not change when a different user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Try with simple way, in your filter class set your attribute to session

```
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);
        httpSession.setAttribute("loginId", loginId);
```

In the other class, you can get the "loginId" from session ...

```
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);
        String loginId= (String) httpSession.getAttribute("loginId");
```

Comment: Do you debug your code? When your session value is changed to null!

Comment: I got it..Thank you very much!